# How to draw a 2-cell using xymatrix?

Tags: diagrams, xymatrix

How to do something like this

[image]

using xymatrix?

Comment: what have you tried, please?  there's a very similar example on p.43 of the manual `xyrefer.pdf` (`texdoc xyrefer`).  that might help.

Answer (score 2):

with `tikz-cd` (its syntax is to my opinion less cryptic as at `xymatrix`):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r, bend  left=60, ""{name=U}]
  \ar[r, bend right=60, ""{name=D,below}]
        & B \ar[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, "\varphi" description]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

for details see `tikz-cd` documentation, page 8 and 11.

Answer (score 1):

I adding, now, my proposal with [`xymatrix`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=1pc@R=1.5pc{ 
X 
\ar@/^1.5pc/[rr]_{\quad}^{f}="1" 
\ar@/_1.5pc/[rr]_{g}="2" 
&& Y 
\ar@{}"1";"2"|(0.135){\,}="7" 
\ar@{}"1";"2"|(0.875){\,}="8" 
\ar@{=>}|-{\varphi}"7" ;"8"}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My problem was the vertical arrow in the middle LOL. Thanks anyway =)

Comment: I ended up using tikz ^.^